# How do I get grunt mocha test report in web?

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js

Since I saw my grunt.js configure have the `test: options: { port: 9001, ...` , instead of run the test on cli, can I view the test result from localhost:9001/index.html ? how can I achieve that?

PS: the node module is Grunt-mocha-test

Comment: Right off the bat with a Google search, I can see 3 grunt plugins to run Mocha tests. Please update your question to indicate which one you are using.

Comment: it's called grunt-mocha-test :)